# Multiple Image to Video with AVAsset Requires high memory

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, avfoundation, avassetwriter

I have seen the most of the questions(asked on the stackoverflow) on how to create video when input images are more than 500.I tried with all the answers provided to create video from Images (more than 500 images), but they give high memory usage and hence my app crashed due to high memory usage.

I tried this link but,did not get satisfactory result.
[iOS5 AVFoundation image to video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7371428/ios5-avfoundation-image-to-video)

[iOS- CVPixelBufferCreate memory cannot release correctly when making image to video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28409041/ios-cvpixelbuffercreate-memory-cannot-release-correctly-when-making-image-to-vi)

[create video from array of UIImages and save the video to iPhone library. AVAssetLibrary +AVFoundation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732302/create-video-from-array-of-uiimages-and-save-the-video-to-iphone-library-avasse?rq=1)

Apart from this i had tried one more link. Please help me to create video from when there are more than 500 images. 
Thanks.

Comment: find solution??

Answer (score 1):

Don't generate the movie on the main thread as is being done with the [iOS- CVPixelBufferCreate memory cannot release correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28409041/ios-cvpixelbuffercreate-memory-cannot-release-correctly-when-making-image-to-vi) ... example.

Secondly add a @autoreleasepool within your loop that processes the individual movie frames.